# custom Context used outside the provider error message

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I created a custom Context and I created a check to find if I use the context inside its provider.

```
const DarkModeContext = createContext();

function useDarkMode() {
 const context = useContext(DarkModeContext);
 if (context === undefined)
   throw new Error("DarkModeColntext wad used outside of DarkModeProvider");

 return context;
}
```

later on I added an initial data to the context so it will never be undefined.

```
const DarkModeContext = createContext({
  isDarkMode: false,
  toggleDarkMode: () => {},
});
```

my question is what should I change to get this error msg again if I use it outside the provider.

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues using useContext without a context provider. In this case, the returned value will be the defaultValue you passed to createContext for that context.
To ensure that you are using a context inside a provider, you should not pass defaultValue to createContext, but instead set an initial value in the context provider.

```
const DarkModeContext = createContext();

function useDarkMode() {
 const context = useContext(DarkModeContext);
 if (context === undefined)
   throw new Error("DarkModeColntext wad used outside of DarkModeProvider");

 return context;
}

<DarkModeContext.Provider value={{isDarkMode: false, toggleDarkMode: () => {}}}>
</DarkModeContext.Provider>
```

Or you can set a specific default value (for ex: null value or isDarkMode = undefined) to createContext and check it in consumer component.

Comment: I mean before I added the default value into the `createContext` the if worked but rn the if will always be true. I am adding it in the create context and not in the value to get it auto complete. also by doing it your way I override my toggleDarkMode function

Comment: As I mentioned last, you can create context with a specific default value.
For ex: const DarkModeContext = createContext({
  isDarkMode: undefined,
  toggleDarkMode: () => {},
});
And detect error like this.
if (context?.isDarkMode === undefined)
   throw new Error("DarkModeColntext wad used outside of DarkModeProvider");

Comment: but then how can I change it to false as default if it is inside the provider?